# Android: How to display item at the center in GridView based on different number of items generated

Tags: android, gridview, center

May I know is there any ways to align the item in `GridView` to be displayed at the center if there is only one item generated from the adapter. If there are two items generated from adapter, it fits the interface nicely, but if there is only one item, it will be shown on the left. I know this is because I set the `android:numColumns="2"`, but is there any ways to make it dynamically like if only one item is generated, then it will be shown on the center.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE of my XML code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout">

        <TextView
            android:text="**Recommendation For You**"
            android:layout_width="800dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="(Most people will order below food item as well!)"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/gridView" />

        <TextView
            android:text="(Click on the VIEW button below for more information!)"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_above="@+id/viewButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:text="View"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#82CAFA"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/viewButton"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView14" />

        <Button
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:background="#82CAFA"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView14" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In your custom Grid View Row Layout set layout_gravity to center and in gridview set numColumns="auto_fit"

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/gridView" />

change it to

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/gridView" />
```

Comment: post you grid row layout, so that i can go through

Comment: <GridView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

change it to 

 <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: I try to replace my code with urs, but the result still the same. Not shown at the middle though.

Comment: okk..you have used both layout_gravity and gravity both use only gravity